# WordPress (localhost) & webmatrix Images have disappeared

Tags: php, css, wordpress, webmatrix

I built a simple site yesterday using the Tesseract theme. Everything went great, I've added custom logos, and background images on every page.
I looked at it this morning, and all of the images have disappeared, leaving my site looking terrible!

I've googled around already and found some similar issues, the solutions to which I've already tried.
I also tried turning on static content in IIS7.

The images are in my media gallery on the wp-admin dashboard.

I'm using webmatrix to run it locally, do I have to turn anything else on to get the images to display that would have been automatically turned on yesterday after I installed?

Any help is very very welcome,

Comment: Are there errors in your error log? Are they returning 404 errors or 500's? Can you see the images in the media gallery but not on your site?

Comment: That's right, where do I find the error log? It's a shame I lost my old stackoverflow account details or I'd post screenshots! The images (except for the background image which just doesn't appear) have just been replaced with placeholder text such as "WhiteLogo1"

Comment: If you are using Chrome you can open the developer tools to see what HTTP code is returned for each request (document, images, css, etc). Your error log location will depend on your OS and webserver. It's been forever since I used Windows but Google should know...

Comment: Also if you look in your WordPress install under `/wp-content/uploads/YEAR/MONTH` you should see your uploaded files. Make sure that the "thumbnail" images are there as well, and that their names match what you are seeing in the HTML document.

Comment: Ah thanks, here we are: http://localhost:59514/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Home-Background.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (URL Rewrite Module Error.)

Comment: That means there is a configuration issue with your webserver - it shouldn't be trying to rewrite that URL as it points to static content. On Apache this problem would be in the VHost or `.htaccess` config, so on IIS I think it's `web.properties`? Try clearing out to a basic install.

Comment: In C:\Users\userDocuments\My Web Sites\wordpress\wp-content\uploads\2015\08, there are all of my uploaded images, but thhe sizes of the images have been appended on the end of the file name, for example, the error above is looking for home-background.jpg, but there are 6 images called home-background-272x182.jpg etc.   Edit - not sure if it's worth mentioning or not, but my C;/ drive is a SSD.

Comment: So, in the folder mentioned above, all of the missing images didn't have a thumbnail of the correct image (just the windows 8.1 default thumbnail). So I deleted those and moved in the correct images, and that's fixed it! However, are they just going to disappear again tomorrow?

Comment: Can't answer that question... unclear how they were deleted in the first place, but it shouldn't happen. There are also plugins that you can use to regenerate your thumbnail images (those are the ones appended with the size, they are pregenerated for performance) if you were to change the size, etc (maybe you tried a different theme with different thumbnail sizes and it seemed to work because of browser caching?). Too many variables to know for sure :)

Comment: Well thanks for your help anyway, if you want to write what I did as an answer instead of a comment I'll thumbs up it. :)